# MongoDB $near and $geoNear gives location with huge difference from real one

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

i noticed that mongoDB $near and $geoNear returns around 1km bigger distance than should be.

Point1 (current location): 
lat: 54.8985,
long: 23.9036,

Point2 (location in DB): 
"location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                54.91689, 
                23.97423
            ]
        }

based on multiple libraries distance should be around **4.7KM**

however mongodb returns: "calcDistance" : 8082 = **8km**

DIFFERENCE is **4 KM**!
You can check it here:

I have tried both spherical and non-spehrical and tried both $geowNear and $near

my code:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 54.8985, 23.9036 ] },
                    distanceField: 'calcDistance',
                    maxDistance: 5 * 1000,
                 }
    }
    ])
```

[image]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Look slike $near and $geoNear need lat and long swapped. That was a problem.
Refer to this: [geoNear returns incorrect distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819231/geonear-returns-incorrect-distance)